# Topological embeddings of non-compact, complete metric spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Given a completely metrizable space, say that it has property X if it can be embedded in some metric space such that its image is not closed. For example, the real line R can be embedded, topologically, in itself as (0,1) which is not closed. A compact space such as S^1, however, clearly cannot be embedded in any metric space in this way.

1. Is it true that a space has property X iff it can be embedded in itself in this way? My intuition says no, but I can't think of a counterexample offhand, partly because I don't know any interesting non-compact metric spaces.
2. Is property X equivalent to not being compact? If every non-compact (completely metrizable) space has a metrizable compactification then this is easy, but I don't know whether that is the case, although I suspect it might be. Which leads onto the following weaker question:
3. Given a space which does not have property X, can it be embedded in a space which does? Here my intuition says yes, this should be the case, but I can't think of a more general approach for constructing a suitable embedding space than compactification which, as I said, I can't prove will give a metrizable space. I don't think I know enough topology (I've only taken a couple of basic undergraduate courses).

Edit: 3. above should read "given a space which has property X, can it be embedded in a space which does not?

Comment: A metrizable space has a metrizable compactification if and only if it's second-countable (equivalently, separable).  The direction you care about is clear, since any subspace of a compact metric space is second-countable.

Comment: A metrizable topological space S is compact if and only if every metric on S that induces this topology is complete.


Comment: Thanks to everyone who's contributed, you've all been very helpful. I'm embarrassed to admit it didn't occur to me that 2 might not imply 3 - I'm still not used to thinking of infinite chains of inclusion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to 2 is yes. Let $(X,d)$ be complete but not compact, then for some $r>0$ it has a countable r-separated subset $S=\{s_i\}:i=1,2,\dots$. Let $d'$ be the maximal metric on $X$ satisfying $d'\le d$ and $d'(s_i,s_j)\le r/\min(i,j)$ for all $i,j$. Then $(X,d')$ is homeomorphic to $(X,d)$ - in fact, the identity map is a local isometry - but $d'$ is not complete. So we have embedded the space into the completion of $(X,d')$ as a non-closed subset.

The metric $d'$ can be constructed explicitly: $d'(x,y)$ is the minimum of $d(x,y)$ and the infimum of sums $d(x,s_i)+d(x,s_j)+r/\min(i,j)$ over all pairs of $i,j$. Verifying the triangle inequality is straightforward.

As for 3, the answer is no, because you cannot embed any complete space into a compact space. For example, a non-separable Banach space cannot be so embedded, as Qiaochu Yuan explained in comments.

**Update.** It seems that I misunderstood Q3. As stated, it asks whether every compact space can be embedded into a complete non-compact one. The answer is of course yes, as Ady noticed.

Comment: Sorry, the question as you interpreted it was actually the question I'd meant to ask! I've corrected it above. But thanks to Ady for your answer - sadly, any apparent good intuition on my part is purely coincidental.

Answer (score 6):

Any metric space can be isometrically embedded into some Banach space *E*. And *E* has the property X, since it can be topologically embedded into itself as its open unit ball, which is clearly not closed in *E*. Therefore, the answer to *3.* is **YES**, and the intuition of Robin Saunders is very good.

---

This is just to clarify some things. For this, let $(M,d)$ be a complete
metric space.

It is pretty clear that a compact metric space cannot have "the
property X". Conversely, asumming that $M$ is non-compact and that $d$ is bounded, by taking
into consideration the equivalent metric $d^{*}\left(x,y\right)$= $\sup_{t\in M}$ $\mid f(x)\cdot d(x,t)$ $-f\left(y\right)\cdot d\left(y,t\right)\mid$, where $f:M$ $\rightarrow$ $(0,\infty)$
is bounded and continuous and inf$_{M}$ $f$ = 0, one easily obtain that $(M,d^*)$
is not complete.

Consequently, $M$ has "the property X" iff it is non-compact.

Now, every separable metric space can be embedded into the Hilbert
cube, which has not "the property X" .

[Note that on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube)
you'll find "every separable metric space can be isometrically
embedded into the Hilbert cube", which is obviously not true.]

OTOH, any subspace of a separable metric space is separable, too.
And any compact metric space is, clearly, separable.

Therefore, $M$ is embeddable into a space having not "the property
X" iff $M$ is separable.

Comment: The "min metric" is not always a metric.


Comment: @Sergei Ivanov Of course you have right. Thank you. I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to 1. is definitely no: a regular tree of valency at least $3$ is a counter-example. An embedding into itself must have closed image due to the combinatorial constraints. However, it can easily be embedded into a plane with non-closed image.